# How do I change a project's id in SBT 1.0?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a bunch of SBT 0.13 project definitions that look like this:

```
lazy val coreBase = crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure).in(file("core"))
  .settings(...)
  .jvmConfigure(_.copy(id = "core"))
  .jsConfigure(_.copy(id = "coreJS"))

lazy val core = coreBase.jvm
lazy val coreJS = coreBase.js
```

(Mostly because I'm resentful about having to maintain Scala.js builds and don't want to have to type the `JVM` suffix every time I'm changing projects, etc.)

This doesn't compile in SBT 1.0 because `Project` doesn't have a `copy` method now.

Okay, let's check [the migration guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html).

> Many of the case classes are replaced with pseudo case classes generated using Contraband. Migrate `.copy(foo = xxx)` to `withFoo(xxx)`.

Cool, let's try it.

```
build.sbt:100: error: value withId is not a member of sbt.Project
  .jvmConfigure(_.withId("core"))
                  ^
```

So I [asked on Gitter](https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt?at=59b5b846210ac2692015db46) and got crickets.

The links for the 1.0 API docs actually point to something now, which is nice, but they're not very helpful in [this case](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0.1/api/sbt/Project.html), and trying to read the SBT source gives me a headache. I'm not in a rush to update to 1.0, but I'm going to have to at some point, I guess, and maybe some helpful person will have answered this by then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(This answer has been edited with information about sbt 1.1.0+ and sbt-crossproject 0.3.1+, which significantly simplify the whole thing.)

With sbt 1.1.0 and later, you can use `.withId("core")`. But there's better with sbt-crossproject 0.3.1+, see below.

<del>I don't know about changing the ID of a `Project`, but</del> here is also a completely different way to solve your original issue, i.e., have `core`/`coreJS` instead of `coreJVM/coreJS`. The idea is to customize `crossProject` to use the IDs you want to begin with.

First, you'll need to use [sbt-crossproject](https://github.com/scala-native/sbt-crossproject). It is the new "standard" for compilation across several platforms, co-designed by @densh from Scala Native and myself (from Scala.js). Scala.js 1.x will allways use sbt-crossproject, but it is also possible to use sbt-crossproject with Scala.js 0.6.x. For that, follow [the instructions in the readme](https://github.com/scala-native/sbt-crossproject#migration-from-scalajs-default-crossproject). In particular, don't forget the "shadowing" part:

```scala
// Shadow sbt-scalajs' crossProject and CrossType from Scala.js 0.6.x
import sbtcrossproject.{crossProject, CrossType}
```

sbt-crossproject is more flexible than Scala.js' hard-coded `crossProject`. This means you can customize it more easily. In particular, it has a generic notion of `Platform`, defining how any given platform behaves.

For a cross JVM/JS project, the new-style `crossProject` invocation would be

```scala
lazy val coreBase = crossProject(JVMPlatform, JSPlatform)
  .crossType(CrossType.Pure)
  .in(file("core"))
  .settings(...)
  .jvmConfigure(_.copy(id = "core"))
  .jsConfigure(_.copy(id = "coreJS"))

lazy val core = coreBase.jvm
lazy val coreJS = coreBase.js
```

Starting with sbt-crossproject 0.3.1, you can simply tell it not to add the platform suffix for one of your platforms. In your case, you want to avoid the suffix for the JVM platform, so you would write:

```scala
lazy val coreBase = crossProject(JVMPlatform, JSPlatform)
  .withoutSuffixFor(JVMPlatform)
  .crossType(CrossType.Pure)
  ...

lazy val core = coreBase.jvm
lazy val coreJS = coreBase.js
```

and that's all you need to do!

**Old answer, applicable to sbt-crossproject 0.3.0 and before**

`JVMPlatform` and `JSPlatform` are not an ADT; they are designed in an OO style. This means you can create your own. In particular, you can create your own `JVMPlatformNoSuffix` that would do the same as [`JVMPlatform`](https://github.com/scala-native/sbt-crossproject/blob/0.2.2/sbt-crossproject/src/main/scala/sbtcrossproject/JVMCross.scala) but without adding a suffix to the project ID:

```scala
import sbt._
import sbtcrossproject._

case object JVMPlatformNoSuffix extends Platform {
  def identifier: String = "jvm"
  def sbtSuffix: String = "" // <-- here is the magical empty string
  def enable(project: Project): Project = project
  val crossBinary: CrossVersion = CrossVersion.binary
  val crossFull: CrossVersion = CrossVersion.full
}
```

Now that's not quite enough yet, because `.jvmSettings(...)` and friends are defined to act on a `JVMPlatform`, not on any other `Platform` such as `JVMPlatformNoSuffix`. You'll therefore have to redefine that as well:

```scala
implicit def JVMNoSuffixCrossProjectBuilderOps(
    builder: CrossProject.Builder): JVMNoSuffixCrossProjectOps =
  new JVMNoSuffixCrossProjectOps(builder)

implicit class JVMNoSuffixCrossProjectOps(project: CrossProject) {
  def jvm: Project = project.projects(JVMPlatformNoSuffix)

  def jvmSettings(ss: Def.SettingsDefinition*): CrossProject =
    jvmConfigure(_.settings(ss: _*))

  def jvmConfigure(transformer: Project => Project): CrossProject =
    project.configurePlatform(JVMPlatformNoSuffix)(transformer)
}
```

Once you have all of that in your build (hidden away in a `project/JVMPlatformNoSuffix.scala` in order not to pollute the `.sbt` file), you can define the above cross-project as:

```scala
lazy val coreBase = crossProject(JVMPlatformNoSuffix, JSPlatform)
  .crossType(CrossType.Pure)
  .in(file("core"))
  .settings(...)

lazy val core = coreBase.jvm
lazy val coreJS = coreBase.js
```

without any need to explicitly patch the project IDs.

Comment: I created https://github.com/scala-native/sbt-crossproject/pull/61 to implement this idea. I think this pattern is common enough to include it directly in the plugin.

Comment: Thanks again, @sjrd! I'm accepting this answer but if someone has an easy way to change the `id` directly I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: @TravisBrown I updated my answer for sbt 1.1.0+ and sbt-crossproject 0.3.1+, both of which significantly simplify the solution.